# Googlesheets: How to name multiple columns with arrayformula when using split

Tags: split, google-sheets, array-formulas

I am using `ARRAYFORMULA`  together with `SPLIT` as you can see in [this Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SbnEMLNK2qyTJdir-zLSsROXwJLobGaVa_KJFML1PSE/edit#gid=838311358). The Formula for B column is this:

```
=arrayformula( if( row(B:B)=1, "Protokoll",IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",SPLIT(A:A, "/")  )))
```

Unfortunately, All columns (B–G) are being named the same as defined in the `ARRAYFORMULA` in column B. However I want them to be named like this:

> B=Protocol, C=Root, D=Level 1, E=Level 2

and so on.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the heading manually in `B1:G1`
Use the `ARRAYFORMULA` in `B2`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work because i define B:B and A:A in the array in terms of being applied to all rows no matter how many columns there are. I get an error `#REF` with your method.

Comment: Use `A2:A` and `B2:B`